# Delphi VirtualTreeview.OnAfterItemPaint issue when scrolling?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I'm getting issues drawing using **OnAfterItemPaint** event when horizontal scrolling is performed.

Basically what I want to achieve is the merging of selected cells effect, say for example 1 text for column 1 & 2, another text for column 3 & 4, etc... So far VT doesn't have any support for column merging, so I have to manually draw it.

Is there a workaround or another event that I should use instead?

Using: Delphi 7 + VirtualTreeview 4.8.5

Event source:

```
begin
  TargetCanvas.TextOut(ItemRect.Left+ VT1.OffsetX, ItemRect.Top,
    '1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF');
end;
```

Before scroll:

[alt text http://a.imagehost.org/0869/screen1.gif](http://a.imagehost.org/0869/screen1.gif)

After scroll (Scroll Right, then Scroll Left):

[alt text http://a.imagehost.org/0645/screen2.gif](http://a.imagehost.org/0645/screen2.gif)

Comment: Do you have this connected to every column, or just one?  If every column, then won't you be writing the same string in all columns, and they'll overlap?

Comment: @Argalatyr: The event can't be connected to columns, it's called exactly once for every item (row) after all column texts have been painted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say what you want to achieve, but seeing that you have a long text that spans multiple columns I'm not sure you use the proper event - usually you want text to be truncated if it's too long for its column.

Anyway, the best thing is to read section 5.2 "Paint cycles and stages" in the [VirtualTreeView.pdf](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=67) documentation file, and find the proper event to be used for what you want to paint. For `OnAfterItemPaint` it states:

> The after item paint stage is used to add node specific stuff like frames and the like
>   which concern all columns of that node and is called once per node.

so I guess it's probably **not** the one you want to use.

**Edit:**

OK, if you're going for the merging of cells you only need to remove the addition of `VT1.OffsetX` (and add `VT1.TextMargin` instead) to get the correct behaviour. This assumes of course you want to start the text output in the first (index 0) column, otherwise you have to calculate the horizontal text position from the column widths.

But from the description of the paint stages I still would rather use the `BeforeItemPaint` event and set the `CustomDraw` var parameter to `True` to skip any default painting.

Comment: @mghie: I trying to do the cell merging effect. Say merge column 1 & 2, thus truncation will occur if the text width is larger than the width of col 1 & 2. I was guessing this event was mostly suitable for this task, but it goes berserk when scrolling occurs. :P

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been fixed, I should have used TextMargin instead of OffsetX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
TreeOptions.AutoOptions := TreeOptions.AutoOptions + [toAutoSpanColumns];
```

It pretty much does what you need. They only issue might be that you can't specify which columns it is enabled for. You can probably get around this by limitation by setting the celltext to a whitespace for the columns you don't want to span into.