# VirtualStringTree aligned text and gridlines

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a virtualstringtree (Gridlines enabled) with X headers and x roots.
I would like to add children (at least 1) to the roots that have only 1 text which is in the middle and goes through all the headers (independent). So no matter if I resize the headers, etc. the text is always aligned to the actual client size of the VirtualStringTree.

Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: @UliGerhardt thank you. That was it! Post your answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: the last answer. autospawn columns.

Comment: Actually, I didn't figure out how to center the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like cell merging. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516082/delphi-virtualtreeview-onafteritempaint-issue-when-scrolling), for example, where the solution is to include `toAutoSpanColumns` in `TreeOptions.AutoOptions`.

If you want center-aligned text, override `OnDrawText` accordingly. Something like:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1DrawText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  const Text: WideString; const CellRect: TRect; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  r := CellRect;
  Windows.DrawTextW(TargetCanvas.Handle, PWideChar(Text), Length(Text), r, DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
  DefaultDraw := False;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you :) How about centering the text?